# gmapping on pioneer p3dx robots not able to publish on /map

Tags: slam, navigation, p3dx, slam-gmapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create map using kinect . The following are the commands that i executed :-

$ roscore

$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch

$ rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan image:=/camera/depth/image_raw

$ rosrun tf static_transform_publisher -0.27 0.0 0.6 0.0 0.0 0.0 base_link camera_link 100

$ rosrun ROSARIA Rosaria _port:=/dev/ttyS0 RosAria/pose:=odom
//the above command is for p3dx. It  publishes nav_msgs::odom on /RosAria/pose as its /odom

$ rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=scan

Here gmapping is showing the following warning    [ WARN] [1450879595.939251882]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.

but when I  created a fake odom publisher gmapping worked.

So , help me out to find why is the /odom of rosaria is not able to drive gmapping.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223021/gmapping-on-pioneer-p3dx-robots-not-able-to-publish-on-/map/) by [sar1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/25409/sar1994/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-12-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a synchronisation problem between the robot and the workstation computers. I used chrony for synchronising both and it worked !!

---

Originally posted by [sar1994](https://answers.ros.org/users/25409/sar1994/) with karma: 46 on 2016-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0